# where is the entry of hypercalls in xen hypervisor?

Tags: memory-management, xen

I need this for checking the activity of the normal and probe operation.If there are two virtual machines VM1(attacker) and VM2 (Victim). Both are accessing the cache memory. I need this for to differentiate in both attacker and victim. How to differentiate between the hypercalls from different VM